# Static Library Xcode on every compile

Tags: ios, xcode, static-libraries, libraries

Every time I compile my project in Xcode it's doing 'creating static libraries', for my sub-projects that I have added. This takes a noticeable amount of time.

Is it somehow possible to make Xcode remember these steps, and save the static libs for the next time? It should only need to do the steps when I changed some of the code in these libs.

Sometimes it's even doing a full recompile of the libraries without any reason.

Any idea how I can fix this?